# gnome-panel messed up after installing ATI driver

Tags: 11.10, drivers, ati, gnome, fglrx

After installing the proprietary ati driver, the gnome-panel in the gnome3 shell is completely messed up. uninstalling the driver doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install the 11.9 driver manually what overwrites the driver (11.8). Download the new Catalyst Driver here http://support.amd.com/, then change to the directory where the driver is located, then:

```
sudo sh ati-driver-installer....run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric
```

install the *.deb's with

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

reboot. Now it should be overwritten. Gnome Shell still has graphic bugs though, but it runs.

Comment: I went back to the "radeon" driver by purging everything (sic!) of the flgrx driver. Took me a while - this is a very big help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver